# Cargar / Incrustar archivo pdf local desde ModelAndView en aplicación java con spring

Tags: java, spring, pdf, java-ee

Tengo una aplicación **Java EE** en la que intento cargar en un `dialog` un archivo pdf.

Los archivos pdf, que se guardan a través de la aplicación se guardan en un directorio local (`C:\opt\archivo.pdf`).

Desde el controlador, recupero el archivo y consigo abrirlo como se abre cualquier archivo desde el explorador de windows.

**Clase controlador** (`PoliticasController.java`)

```
public ModelAndView mostrarPolitica(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, PoliticaCommand form) throws Exception
{
    MUsuarios usuario = getUserSession(request);
    MUsuariosPoliticas up = usuariosBL.findPoliticaPendiente(usuario.getIdUsuario(), new BigDecimal(form.getTpProceso()));

    form.setFkPolitica(up.getId().getFkPolitica());
    // Recuperamos el último fichero asociado a la política
    QRPoliticasFicheros pf = new QRPoliticasFicheros();
    pf.setIdPolitica(form.getFkPolitica());
    pf = (QRPoliticasFicheros) politicasBL.findFirstByExample(pf, null);

    if(pf != null && pf.getIdPolitica().equals(form.getFkPolitica())) {
        // Se establece la codificación a la petición
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        // Se obtienen los nombres del fichero
        String nArchivo = pf.getNombreoriginal();
        String nArchivoNuevo = pf.getNombrenuevo();

        // Se establece la ruta del fichero
        String ruta = M.sg("nombre.carpeta.archivos") + File.separator;
        String contenido = "";

        // Se obtiene el archivo            
        try {
            int nbLectura;
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream sourceFile = null;

            File file = new File(ruta + nArchivoNuevo);

            if(file != null && file.exists()) {

                sourceFile = new FileInputStream(file);
                OutputStream pw = response.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(pw);

                while ((nbLectura = sourceFile.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    ps.write(buffer, 0, nbLectura);
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Fichero '" + ruta + nArchivoNuevo
                        + "' no encontrado");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error", e);
            throw e;
        }

    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Vista** (`politica.jspf`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<fmt:message key="path.estatico.general"/>/js/printThis.js"></script>

<div id="politicaDialog" style="display:none">
    <div id="menus" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div id="menuGrid" class="menuBar cornerAll">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li style="float:left;" id="li_volver"><a href="#" title="<fmt:message key="comun.volver" />" onclick="politicaDialogo.dialog('close');" class="volver cornerAll"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li style="float:right; margin-right:5px;" id="li_imprimir"><a class="imprimir cornerAll" onclick="$('#politicaContent').printThis();" title="Imprimir" href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="limpiar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="politicaContent" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; margin: 5px; padding: 0.2em">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var politicaDialogo;

    var w = 800;
    if (($(window).width()-40)<w){
        w=$(window).width()-40;
    }
    var h = 1000;
    if (($(window).height()-40)<h){
        h=$(window).height()-40;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        politicaDialogo=$("#politicaDialog").dialog({
            width: w,
            height: h,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            resizable: false,
            title: '<fmt:message key="comun.dialogo.politica" />',
            close: function(event, ui) {
                politicaDialogo.hide();
            }
        });

        //Esto se pone porque en alguna ocasion el dialog aparece directamente abierto
        politicaDialogo.dialog('close');
    });


    function mostrarPolitica(tpproceso) {
        console.log("Estoy aqui");
        $.post("politica.html",
            { action: 'mostrarPolitica', tpProceso: tpproceso, osc: Math.random()},
                function(respuesta) {
                    if (respuesta.error){
                        alert('<fmt:message key="comun.error.cargar" />');
                    }
                    else{
                        //$("#politicaContent").html(respuesta.content);
                    }                   
                }
            , "json"
        );
        document.getElementById('politicaDialog').style.display="block";
        politicaDialogo.dialog('open');
    };  

</script>
```

Entonces, hasta ahora tengo: pulso un botón de la aplicación. Se carga un `dialog` desde la vista `politica.jspf` y además se abre el documento PDF con el lector pdf configurado por defecto en el S.O.

Ahora, quiero incrustar el pdf en el `<div id="politicaContent"...>` del `dialog`.

Para ello he añadido al div un `object` de la siguiente manera:

**Vista modificada** (`politica.jspf`)

```
<div id="politicaContent" style="border:1px solid #AAAAAA; margin: 5px; padding: 0.2em">
        <object  data="data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}"  type='application/pdf' ></object>
    </div>
```

He modificado el controlador añadiendo lo siguiente:

**Cambio en el código del controlador** (`PoliticasController.java`)

```
...
String nArchivo = pf.getNombreoriginal();
String nArchivoNuevo = pf.getNombrenuevo();

// Se establece la ruta del fichero
String ruta = M.sg("nombre.carpeta.archivos") + File.separator;
String contenido = "";


InputStream is = (new URL("localhost:8080//" + ruta + nArchivoNuevo)).openStream();
byte[] pdfBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

return new ModelAndView("politica", "form", form).addObject("pdf", new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes)));
```

Pero surgen dos errores:

1. Salta un mensaje del navegador que dice lo siguiente: (**Acceso denegado**). Lo he comprobado y se debe al código `<object>` añadido en la vista. No se si es que intenta cargar un pdf al iniciar la vista y por eso falla.

[image: Acceso denegado]

2. Falla en la línea `InputStream is = (new URL("localhost:8080//" + ruta + nArchivoNuevo)).openStream();` mostrando en consola lo siguiente:

> ```
> 15-11-2018 12:16:45 DEBUG PoliticasController Trying to find handler for exception class [java.net.MalformedURLException]
> 15-11-2018 12:16:45 DEBUG PoliticasController Trying to find handler for exception superclass [java.net.MalformedURLException]
> 15-11-2018 12:16:45 DEBUG PoliticasController Trying to find handler for exception superclass [java.io.IOException]
> 15-11-2018 12:16:45 DEBUG PoliticasController Trying to find handler for exception superclass [java.lang.Exception]
> ```

He quitado el `localhost:8080//` y tampoco funciona.

No se si hay alguna forma más fácil de hacerlo, he buscado y no encuentro nada, igual me estoy complicando demasiado o hay soluciones más prácticas

**EDITADO:**

Para aclarar más la pregunta, añado la siguiente información.

La vista `politica.jspf` (que no es más que un `dialog`) está incluída dentro de otra vista llamada `selector.jsp`, de manera que cuando se hace clic en un botón de selector.jsp se llama a una función `seleccionaTpproceso` desde la cuál se llama a la función `mostrarPolitica()` de `politica.jspf` que es el que está mapeada con el controlador `politicasController.java`.

**El código de la vista** `selector.jsp` **es:**

```
<%@ include file="./politica.jspf" %>
...
seleccionaTpproceso = function(id, contingencias, visibleExcel){
    mostrarPolitica(id);
};

...
<div class="bloque" style="padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 40%;">
    <h2><fmt:message key="selector.titulo"/></h2>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="boton" items="${form.botones}">
            <li onclick="seleccionaTpproceso('${boton.id.idAuto}', ${boton.contingencias}, ${boton.visibleExcel});">${boton.trdDtpprocesoRiesgo}</li>   
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

La URL de la app, al estar en realidad dentro de la vista `selector.jsp`, es: **`http://localhost:8080/pwc_riesgos/selector.html`**

Con esto, al ejecutar en chrome recibo por pantalla los siguientes errores en función de la vista que ponga en `return new ModelAndView(nombre_vista, "form", form).addObject("pdf", new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes)));`

- Con `new ModelAndView("/politica", "form", form).addObject("pdf", new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes)));` recibo el error 404:

> ```
> POST http://localhost:8080/pwc_riesgos/politica.html 404 (Not Found)
> ajax @ jquery-1.4.4.min.js:141
> post @ jquery-1.4.4.min.js:134
> mostrarPolitica @ selector.html:430
> seleccionaTpproceso @ selector.html:463
> onclick @ selector.html:501
> Show 3 more blackboxed frames
>
> POST http://localhost:8080/pwc_riesgos/politica.html net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 404 (Not Found)
> ajax  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:141
> post  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:134
> mostrarPolitica   @   selector.html:430
> seleccionaTpproceso   @   selector.html:463
> onclick   @   selector.html:501
> ```

- Con `new ModelAndView("/selector", "form", form).addObject("pdf", new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes)));` recibo el error 500:

> ```
> POST http://localhost:8080/pwc_riesgos/politica.html net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ajax  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:141
> post  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:134
> mostrarPolitica   @   selector.html:430
> seleccionaTpproceso   @   selector.html:463
> onclick   @   selector.html:501
>
> POST http://localhost:8080/pwc_riesgos/politica.html net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ajax  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:141
> post  @   jquery-1.4.4.min.js:134
> mostrarPolitica   @   selector.html:430
> seleccionaTpproceso   @   selector.html:463
> onclick   @   selector.html:501
> ```

Comment: No se si sera pero estas intentando localizarlo a travez de `localhost:8080//`

Comment: No sé exactamente cuál es el problema, pero lo de acceso denegado no es por no encontrarlo en local, ya que no lo estás pasando como una ruta sino como un binario en Base64. ¿Te da un error HTTP 403? Deberías explicar mejor el error que te da: ¿es en el navegador o en log del servidor?

Comment: He probado sin localhost:8080// y tampoco funciona. @JDev

Comment: He editado la pregunta. No da error HTTP: simplemente se para la ejecución y el object no muestra nada quedandose el contenido vacío. Por consola muestra los mensajes que he indicado en la pregunta @PabloLozano

Answer (score 1):

Para la aplicación que está siendo ejecutada desde tu contenedor de aplicaciones JEE, el fichero PDF está en la máquina local, lo que tienes que hacer es leer el fichero local y mandarlo al cliente que hizo la petición.
Por tanto, deberías crear un `FileInputStream` con el path de ese fichero:

```
InputStream is= new FileInputStream("C:\opt\archivo.pdf");
byte[] pdfBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
...
```

Piensa en tu "servidor" y en el código que ejecuta como una aplicación de escritorio más, que manda datos a otras computadoras. No deberías (generalmente) pedirte datos a ti mismo usando peticiones HTTP.

Comment: He conseguido que lea el fichero haciendo lo que dices, pero no consigo cargarlo en el la vista.

Comment: ¿Da un error en el navegador? En principio el HTML parece correcto

Comment: He editado la pregunta con una imagen del mensaje que sale. Sigue saliendo ese mensaje. Cuando le doy  a ok para cerrarla, se abre ya mi `dialog` con el contenido del `<div id="politicaContent"...>` vacío. Ni el navegador ni eclipse muestran errores por consola.

Comment: Ese parece un problema del navegador... ¿con cuál estás probando? ¿Tienes el Adobe Reader instalado? eso suele crear conflictos

Comment: Estoy utilizando IE11. Por requisito tiene que funcionar en este navegador. Tengo instalado Adobe Reader DC

Comment: No tengo ni idea de cómo se puede configurar, pero los navegadores pueden leer por sí mismos los PDF, así que si configuras tu navegador para que no use un visor externo, deberías poder cargar el PDF. Creo que el problema está causado por el hecho de que IE delega la tarea a A. Reader y éste no encuentra el fichero PDF en la cache (por que está embebido en el HTML)

Comment: Vale gracias! Voy a investigar lo que dices a ver si consigo solucionar algo

Comment: He ejecutado en chrome y sale el siguienten estos errores en consola: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` y `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

Comment: Uf, ahí ya me has perdido... un 404 no tiene sentido

Comment: He editado añadiendo más info.